# Custom names detection

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, detection, named-entity-extraction

This is a project in really early phase and I'm trying to find ideas on where to start.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**My problem:**
I have text on one side, and a list of named GraphDB elements on the other (usually the name is either an acronym or a multi-word expression). My texts are not annotated.
I want to detect whenever a name is **explicitly** used in the text. The trick is that it will not necessarily be a perfect string match (for example an acronym can be used to shorten a multi-word expression, or a small part can be left out). So a simple string search will not have a 100% recall (even though it can be used as a starter).

If I just had an input and I wanted it to match it to one of the names, I would do a simple **edit distance** computation and that's it. What bugs me is that I have to do this for a whole text, and I don't know how to approach/break down the problem. 
I cannot break down everything in N-grams because my named entities can be a single word or up to seven words long... Or can I?
I have thousands of Graph elements so I don't think NER can be applied here... Or can it?

**An example could be:**
My list of names is ['Graph Database', 'Manager', 'Employee Number 1']
The text is:

> Every morning, the ***Manager*** browse through the ***Graph Database*** to look for updates. Every evening, ***Employee 1*** updates the ***GraphDB***.

I want in this block of text to map the 4 highlighted portions to their corresponding item in the list.

I have a small background in Machine Learning but I haven't really ever done NLP. To be clear, I do not care about the meaning of these words, I just want to be able to **detect** them.

Thanks

Comment: one or two examples of your data would help to better understand your exact problem.

Comment: @chefhose thanks for the feedback, I updated my original question with a small example of what it could look like.